# where is the duplicate in ON DUPLICATE KEY query?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

**Description:**

I am trying to insert user's preferences into a database. If the user hasn't yet placed any, I want a `insert`, otherwise, I want an `update`. I know I can insert default values in the creation of the user and than exclusively use `update`, but that adds another query (I think)

**Problem:**

I have read up on `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I don't understand it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786141/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-question) is almost the exact question I have but without the answer. The answer says:

> It does sound like it will work for what you want to do as long as you hav the proper column(s) defined as UNIQUE KEY or PRIMARY KEY.

If I do a simple `insert` like so:

```
INSERT INTO table (color, size) VALUES ('blue', '18') ...
```

How will that ever produce at `DUPLICATE KEY`? As far as `mysql` knows it's just another insert and the `id` is auto-incremented. I have the primary key in the table set to unique, but the `insert` isn't going to check against that, right?

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `firm_pref` (
    `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firm_id` int(9) NOT NULL, //user_id in this case
    `header_title` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
    `statement` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
    `footer_content` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I would think that you would have a variable that either holds nothing or the unique ID and you would insert that into the `values` in the proper location. if it is nothing then it would insert a new record, if it has an ID then it would update seeing that there is already a record.

Comment: Can there be two records with the same `firm_id` in this table?

Comment: No, there can not, it's a many-to-one relationship

Comment: Then why do you need `id` column at all?

Comment: I don't really need one I guess, I thought maybe down the future I could list prefs, does that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, unless you want your application to be used by a single person only, you would have to specify someone's user_id in that `INSERT` - when this 'someone' guy or girl updates his/her preferences, right?

This field (`user_id`) is exactly what would be checked by `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

And if you want to insert a new record, just send `NULL` instead:

```
INSERT INTO table (user_id, color, size) VALUES (NULL, 'blue', 18);
```

... so auto-increment will have a chance to move on and save the day. )

**UPDATE:** Take note that to understand that some field should be considered a *unique* identifier, you should mark it as such. Usually it's done naturally, as this field is used as a `PRIMARY KEY`. But sometimes it's not enough; it means some work for `UNIQUE` constraint. For example, in your table it can be used like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `prefs` (
    `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firm_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
     ...
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY (`firm_id`)
);
```

*(or you can add this constraint to the existing table with* `ALTER TABLE prefs ADD UNIQUE (firm_id)` *command)*

Then insert/update query will look like...

```
INSERT INTO prefs(firm_id, header_title, statement, footer_content) 
           VALUES(17, 'blue', '18', 'some_footer')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
           header_title = 'blue', 
           statement = '18', 
           footer_content = 'some_footer';
```

I've built a sort of [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4f1e) in SQL Fiddle. You can play with it some more to better understand that concept. )

Comment: `user_id` isn't auto-incrementing in this table, so I am assuming I can place the value (`user_id`) instead of the `NULL` and still find the duplicate key?

Comment: Let me clarify this: you don't "find" duplicate keys. You have a choice: either update some existing record - or create a new one. The difference between 'new' and 'existing' lies within some unique identifier ('handle') of each record. If you try to insert something with 'non-unique' identifier, it's not a new record by definition; that's how `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works.

Comment: By the way, could you show the structure of the table we're talking about? By `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` or some other means.

Comment: Table structure was added. The issue I am having is that there are many examples on SO and on other sites that show the `insert` queries have values that are clearly not unique and I am wondering how that works? I included a link to a question like that.

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly! Thank you very much! Also, thank you for introducing me to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

For options, you would normally have an `options` table that has a list of available options (like color, size etc), and then a table that spans both your `options` table and `users` table with the users' values.

For example, your `options` table:

```
id | name
=========
1  | color
2  | size
```

Your `users` table:

```
id | name
================
1  | Martin Bean
```

And an `options_users` join table:

```
option_id | user_id | value
===========================
1         | 1       | Blue
2         | 1       | Large
```

With the correct foreign keys set up in your `options_users` table, you can have redundant values removed when an option or user is removed from your system. Also, when saving a user's preferences, you can first delete their previous answers and insert the new ones.

```
DELETE FROM `options_users`
WHERE `user_id` = @user_id;

INSERT INTO `options_users` (`option_id`, `user_id`, `value`)
VALUES (1, @user_id, 'Blue'), (2, @user_id, 'Large');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: are you saying this would be more efficient than using, `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

Comment: Yeah. Using a join table is far better, as it you don't then have to add/drop columns when you change your options.

Comment: But, I am trying to check if the user has already placed data into the database, this would, many times, attempt to delete a non-existent field.

Comment: Not really. It would just delete any previous preferences set by the new user, and insert the fresh batch of preferences.

Comment: in the future though, instead of performing 1 query, this will always fire two, I mean this solves the issue, but I am wondering if this is better. thank you very much!